# Can I read the same config from Apache PropertiesConfiguration multiple times without losing performance?

Tags: java, performance, apache, properties

I have a PropertiesConfiguration object. Can I call getInt(), getString() etc multiple times without being concerned with performance? I mean, it wont read from file every time or in any other way lower the performance of my system?

The alternative is to read all values into a Map during initialization of my class, and use this for lookup, but if I can avoid this without loosing performance I obviously would (less code etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chose and make priority for your requirements:

- Reading a file each time you want properties is not a big problem if you have small amount of requests and if file by itself is small. It also gives you ability to change properties without restarting application (sometimes it should be done like that).
- From other side (what I would prefer), you have to read the file during startup and store information in application cache (like HashMap etc.). If this cache is shared within your application, you may use it in any class you want, and without any performance issues (but take care of concurrent access, depends on your implementation). 

  Also, in this case, you may provide some additional kinda admin screen for changing properties from, as an example, web page and update your cache by some servlet "on the fly" (update cached map with properties + update the file with properties without restarting application)).

In case if you are using Apache Commons as below:

```
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("usergui.properties");
```

And if you look inside source code of PropertiesConfiguration you will find below.

```
/** stores the configuration key-value pairs */
private Map<String, Object> store = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

And if you will look for implementation of getInt() finally you will come to below:

```
/**
 * Read property from underlying map.
 *
 * @param key key to use for mapping
 *
 * @return object associated with the given configuration key.
 */
public Object getProperty(String key)
{
    return store.get(key);
}
```

What means this is second case, where properties are loaded once into a map. I suppose if you need "fresh" properties in some other class, you have to configure it again.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that every time I call getString() etc on my PropertiesConfigration object, it will read from file? I guess I expected that it was read from file the first time, and the value was stored in memory until I somehow triggered the config to update from the file again.

Comment: I've added info I found for getInt() method

Comment: OK, thank you. Then I can the answer to my question in heading is "yes".